# about the Vue.js template only accept one root

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js .
here is a curious question that I want to know :
Why vue.js in the template only accept one root instead of two or furthers?

I'm keen to know about the design principle of vue.js, 
what reason made it design like that?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

To know the design principles, start here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7088#issuecomment-357899727